# Nav, accessibility and tags?

Tags: html, accessibility

I managed to find the following in bootstrap docs when referring to an accordion.

> Be sure to add aria-expanded to the control element. This attribute explicitly defines the current state of the collapsible element to screen readers and similar assistive technologies. If the collapsible element is closed by default, it should have a value of aria-expanded="false". If you’ve set the collapsible element to be open by default using the show class, set aria-expanded="true" on the control instead. The plugin will automatically toggle this attribute based on whether or not the collapsible element has been opened or closed.
>
> Additionally, if your control element is targeting a single collapsible element – i.e. the data-target attribute is pointing to an id selector – you may add an additional aria-controls attribute to the control element, containing the id of the collapsible element. Modern screen readers and similar assistive technologies make use of this attribute to provide users with additional shortcuts to navigate directly to the collapsible element itself.

What accessibility tags should I use when making drop down navigation?

Answer (score 0):

> What accessibility tags should I use when making drop down navigation?

Applications can have accessible behaviours without the use of any special tag. And they can have bad behaviours with the use of ARIA.

The ARIA definition says:

> ARIA defines a way to make Web content and Web applications more accessible to people with disabilities.

But the use, the misuse, the abuse of ARIA can't make accessible something which is not accessible by default.

For instance, yes `aria-expanded` or `aria-haspopup` seem to be a must have, but it won't get of any help without the correct handling of keyboard navigation (javascript), convenient clicking area (css), and : color contrasts, visual cues that this is a dropdown navigation, timing, information hierarchy, ...

The W3C offers [an example of fly-out menu](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/)